# How to handle the unit-test assembly load issue in C#

Tags: c#, visio, vs-unit-testing-framework

While loading assemblies from both x64/x86, I have got exception message as **System.BadImageFormatException** in my unit-test project.
Below is the code and screen shot of the exception I have got while  debugging the test.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Example_Addin;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;
using Visio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;

namespace exampleProject
{

 [TestClass]
 public class exampleUnitTest1
 {   
    
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_example()
    {
        try
        {
          Example exm_obj = new Example();

          string file_path = "test.json";
          string template_file = "template.vssx";



          double height = 0.5;
          double width = 0.5;

          db_obj.read_data_shape_creation(@file_path, 0.5, 0.5, "F06", @template_file, "testing");

        

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception occour");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here, I want to unit test my code with assembly dependencies, but after setting the assembly, I get the above snapped exception and code execution is halted.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the `\bin` directory and rebuild your project?

Comment: No, let me try.

Comment: Same issue still happen.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happen due to my target framework for unit-test and my core-project are not matching. When I have correct both case it is working.

[image]